# Is my code thread-unsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, cyclicbarrier

I have wrote code to understand CyclicBarrier.

My application emulates election. Each rounds selects candidate with small votes and this candidate eliminates from the race for victory.

source:

```
class ElectoralCommission {
    public volatile boolean hasWinner;
    public volatile String winner;
    private List<String> candidates;
    private Map<String, Integer> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    ElectoralCommission(List<String> candidates) {
        this.candidates = candidates;
    }

    public void acceptVote(int index) {
        Integer currentResult = results.get(candidates.get(index));
        results.put(candidates.get(index), currentResult == null ? 1 : currentResult + 1);
    }

    public void clearResults() {
        results.clear();
    }

    public synchronized List<String> getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }

    public String getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }

    public boolean isHasWinner() {
        return hasWinner;
    }

    public void printResults() {
        System.out.println("result:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : results.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("key=" + entry.getKey() + ", value=" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void removeWeakCandidates() {
        int minVoteValue = Collections.min(results.values());
        int maxVoteValue = Collections.max(results.values());
        if (maxVoteValue == minVoteValue) {
            System.out.println("all candidates got same votes count");
        } else {
            List<String> loosers = results.entrySet().stream().filter(i -> i.getValue() == minVoteValue).map(i -> i.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            candidates.removeAll(loosers);
            if (candidates.size() == 1) {
                hasWinner = true;
                winner = candidates.get(0);
            }
        }
        clearResults();
    }
}

class Voter implements Runnable {
    ElectoralCommission electoralCommission;
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    Voter(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier, ElectoralCommission electoralCommission) {
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
        this.electoralCommission = electoralCommission;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!electoralCommission.hasWinner) {
            List<String> candidates = electoralCommission.getCandidates();
            int voteIndex = new Random().nextInt(candidates.size());
            electoralCommission.acceptVote(voteIndex);
            try {
                cyclicBarrier.await(); //wait while all voters vote
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
    }
}

class Main {
    public static final int VOTE_COUNT = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
        candidates.add("candidate_1");
        candidates.add("candidate_2");
        candidates.add("candidate_3");
        candidates.add("candidate_4");
        candidates.add("candidate_5");
        candidates.add("candidate_6");
        candidates.add("candidate_7");
        candidates.add("candidate_8");
        candidates.add("candidate_9");
        candidates.add("candidate_10");
        ElectoralCommission electoralCommission = new ElectoralCommission(candidates);
        CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(VOTE_COUNT, new Summarizer(electoralCommission));
        for (int i = 0; i < VOTE_COUNT; i++) {
            new Thread(new Voter(cyclicBarrier, electoralCommission)).start();
        }

    }
}

class Summarizer implements Runnable {
    ElectoralCommission electoralCommission;

    Summarizer(ElectoralCommission electoralCommission) {
        this.electoralCommission = electoralCommission;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("summarizer");
        electoralCommission.printResults();
        electoralCommission.removeWeakCandidates();
        if (electoralCommission.hasWinner) {
            String winnerName = electoralCommission.getWinner();
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            System.out.println("candidate " + winnerName + " won!");
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

sample output:

```
summarizer
result:
key=candidate_2, value=984
key=candidate_3, value=1004
key=candidate_1, value=1018
key=candidate_6, value=1002
key=candidate_7, value=969
key=candidate_4, value=1031
key=candidate_5, value=1038
key=candidate_10, value=915
key=candidate_8, value=1003
key=candidate_9, value=1034
summarizer
result:
key=candidate_2, value=1096
key=candidate_3, value=1133
key=candidate_1, value=1088
key=candidate_6, value=1144
key=candidate_7, value=1078
key=candidate_4, value=1136
key=candidate_5, value=1100
key=candidate_8, value=1147
key=candidate_9, value=1078
summarizer
result:
key=candidate_2, value=1429
key=candidate_3, value=1488
key=candidate_1, value=1430
key=candidate_6, value=1445
key=candidate_4, value=1410
key=candidate_5, value=1397
key=candidate_8, value=1399
summarizer
result:
key=candidate_2, value=1668
key=candidate_3, value=1697
key=candidate_1, value=1684
key=candidate_6, value=1661
key=candidate_4, value=1679
key=candidate_8, value=1610
summarizer
result:
key=candidate_2, value=2079
key=candidate_3, value=1954
key=candidate_1, value=2003
key=candidate_6, value=2022
key=candidate_4, value=1941
summarizer
result:
key=candidate_2, value=2504
key=candidate_3, value=2481
key=candidate_1, value=2500
key=candidate_6, value=2514
summarizer
result:
key=candidate_2, value=3299
key=candidate_1, value=3284
key=candidate_6, value=3417
summarizer
result:
key=candidate_2, value=4961
key=candidate_6, value=5036
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
candidate candidate_6 won!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

As you can see my last summarizer invocation output following:

```
summarizer
result:
key=candidate_2, value=4961
key=candidate_6, value=5036
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
candidate candidate_6 won!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

I have 10000 voters but 4961 + 5036 = 9997.

Which lost 3 votes ?

### P.S.

I tryed solution with locks:

```
class ElectoralCommission {
    public volatile boolean hasWinner;
    public volatile String winner;
    private List<String> candidates;
    private Map<String, AtomicInteger> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    ElectoralCommission(List<String> candidates) {
        this.candidates = candidates;
    }

    public void acceptVote(int index) {
        AtomicInteger currentResult = results.get(candidates.get(index));
       if(currentResult!=null){
           currentResult.incrementAndGet();
       }
    }

    public void clearResults() {
        results.clear();
    }

    public synchronized List<String> getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }

    public String getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }

    public boolean isHasWinner() {
        return hasWinner;
    }

    public void printResults() {
        System.out.println("result:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger> entry : results.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("key=" + entry.getKey() + ", value=" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void removeWeakCandidates() {
        int minVoteValue = Collections.min(results.values().stream().map(i->i.intValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        int maxVoteValue = Collections.max(results.values().stream().map(i->i.intValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        if (maxVoteValue == minVoteValue) {
            System.out.println("all candidates got same votes count");
        } else {
            List<String> loosers = results.entrySet().stream().filter(i -> i.getValue().intValue() == minVoteValue).map(i -> i.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            candidates.removeAll(loosers);
            if (candidates.size() == 1) {
                hasWinner = true;
                winner = candidates.get(0);
            }
        }
        clearResults();
    }
}

class Voter implements Runnable {
    ElectoralCommission electoralCommission;
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    Voter(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier, ElectoralCommission electoralCommission) {
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
        this.electoralCommission = electoralCommission;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!electoralCommission.hasWinner) {
            List<String> candidates = electoralCommission.getCandidates();
            int voteIndex = new Random().nextInt(candidates.size());
            electoralCommission.acceptVote(voteIndex);
            try {
                cyclicBarrier.await(); //wait while all voters vote
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
    }
}

class Main {
    public static final int VOTE_COUNT = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
        candidates.add("candidate_1");
        candidates.add("candidate_2");
        candidates.add("candidate_3");
        candidates.add("candidate_4");
        candidates.add("candidate_5");
        candidates.add("candidate_6");
        candidates.add("candidate_7");
        candidates.add("candidate_8");
        candidates.add("candidate_9");
        candidates.add("candidate_10");
        ElectoralCommission electoralCommission = new ElectoralCommission(candidates);
        CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(VOTE_COUNT, new Summarizer(electoralCommission));
        for (int i = 0; i < VOTE_COUNT; i++) {
            new Thread(new Voter(cyclicBarrier, electoralCommission)).start();
        }

    }
}

class Summarizer implements Runnable {
    ElectoralCommission electoralCommission;

    Summarizer(ElectoralCommission electoralCommission) {
        this.electoralCommission = electoralCommission;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("summarizer");
        electoralCommission.printResults();
        electoralCommission.removeWeakCandidates();
        if (electoralCommission.hasWinner) {
            String winnerName = electoralCommission.getWinner();
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            System.out.println("candidate " + winnerName + " won!");
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

but I see

```
java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:362)
    at lection2.task3.Voter.run(Main.java:88)
```

line 88:  `cyclicBarrier.await();`

Comment: Check the invariant at each point instead of just the end.  Perhaps that will help you pinpoint where it went awry.

Comment: You have shared variables which are interleaving as multiple threads execute.  Use atomic variables or `synchronized` to avoid this.

Comment: You lost votes in every iteration. In the first one there are 3 less and in the penultimate you have lost only 2. From my point of view there is a concurrency problem. As @TimBiegeleisen has said, you should protect the variables, so 2 threads don not access them at the same time.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen yes - if mark acceptVote synchronized - all works well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems error in method *acceptVote(int index)*

Try to rewrite it use method *ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent* and *AtomicInteger*:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void acceptVote(int index) {
    AtomicInteger currentResult = results.get(candidates.get(index));
    if (currentResult == null) {
        currentResult = results.putIfAbsent(candidates.get(index), new AtomicInteger(1));
        if (currentResult != null) {
            currentResult.getAndIncrement();
        }
    } else {
        currentResult.getAndIncrement();
    }
}
```

something like this...

Comment: But if a number of votes exists, the value is not absent, right?

Comment: @Sergey Morozov please provide more  details

Comment: If you seed the `results` collection in the `ElectoralCommission` constructor, then `acceptVote` becomes `results.get(candidates.get(index)).getAndIncrement();`

Comment: Would it also be possible to use an AtomicInteger in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I tried several times with a synchronized list for candidates, at the results are consistent and as expected:

```
class Main {
    public static final int VOTE_COUNT = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> candidates = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
      .....
}
```

Not the best solution though.

A better solution would be to synchronize just the access to accepted voters. This can be done:

```
class ElectoralCommission {
  //....

    public synchronized void acceptVote(int index) {
        Integer currentResult = results.get(candidates.get(index));
        results.put(candidates.get(index), currentResult == null ? 1 : currentResult + 1);
}
```

but this is not the best way, as it will add lock the whole object. A better approach would be using a lock:

```
    class ElectoralCommission {
  //....
        private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(); 

        public void acceptVote(int index) {
            try {
               lock.lock();
               Integer currentResult = results.get(candidates.get(index));
               results.put(candidates.get(index), currentResult == null ? 1 : currentResult + 1);
           }finally {
               lock.unlock();
           }
        }
```

**Output 1:**

```
result:
key=candidate_6, value=3315
key=candidate_7, value=3315
key=candidate_10, value=3370
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
candidate candidate_10 won!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: This may work but do we really need the synchronized collection?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - not really. You are right. This was the first thing I tried, I am refining the solution. But for the completeness of the response I added the given solution as well. Please edit or suggest improvements :).

Comment: I don't see any problem with the access pattern on the `candidates` collection (in my view, the CyclicBarrier implementation protects all the write-access to it in a single thread that runs exclusively). But I do see the issue with the `acceptVote` implementation, and I would encourage the OP to look into a mix of `ConcurrentMap` and `AtomicInteger`

Answer (score 2):

Building a bit on Sergey's answer, if you seed the `results` collection in the `ElectoralCommission` constructor:

```
ElectoralCommission(List<String> candidates) {
    this.candidates = candidates;
    for (String candidate : candidates) {
        results.put(candidate, new AtomicInteger());
    }
}
```

Then `acceptVote` becomes:

```
public void acceptVote(int index) {
    results.get(candidates.get(index)).getAndIncrement();
}
```

Comment: **results.get(candidates.get(index))** can returns null

Comment: Not if `results` is seeded with default values as I point out in my answer.

Comment: @Sean : using an `ExecutorService` shields you from the `Thread` API, but seeing the `Voter` implementations requires that all 10k `Voters` to be active at once (all threads need to hit the `CyclicBarrier`), the `ExecutorService` has to be carrefully chosen to actually spawn the 10k simulteanous threads. And one might argue that choosing an adequate `ExecutorService` is akin in such a case to spawning the `Thread`s manually. E.g. a `fixedSizeThreadPool` inferior to 10k would not cut it.

Comment: Ah, I had missed that all of the threads needed to be active at the same time. Will remove that bit.

Answer (score 0):

The following variants works for atomics:

```
class ElectoralCommission {
    public volatile boolean hasWinner;
    public volatile String winner;
    private List<String> candidates;
    private Map<String, AtomicInteger> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private Map<String, AtomicInteger> initializeMap() {
        candidates.stream().forEach(i -> results.put(i, new AtomicInteger()));
        return results;
    }

    ElectoralCommission(List<String> candidates) {
        this.candidates = candidates;
        results = initializeMap();
    }

    public void acceptVote(int index) {
        results.get(candidates.get(index)).incrementAndGet();
    }

    public void clearResults() {
        results.clear();
        initializeMap();
    }

    public List<String> getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }

    public String getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }

    public void printResults() {
        System.out.println("result:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger> entry : results.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("key=" + entry.getKey() + ", value=" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void removeWeakCandidates() {
        int minVoteValue = Collections.min(results.values().stream().map(i->i.intValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        int maxVoteValue = Collections.max(results.values().stream().map(i->i.intValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        if (maxVoteValue == minVoteValue) {
            System.out.println("all candidates got same votes count");
        } else {
            List<String> loosers = results.entrySet().stream().filter(i -> i.getValue().intValue() == minVoteValue).map(i -> i.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            candidates.removeAll(loosers);
            if (candidates.size() == 1) {
                hasWinner = true;
                winner = candidates.get(0);
            }
        }
        clearResults();
    }
}

class Voter implements Runnable {
    ElectoralCommission electoralCommission;
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    Voter(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier, ElectoralCommission electoralCommission) {
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
        this.electoralCommission = electoralCommission;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!electoralCommission.hasWinner) {
            List<String> candidates = electoralCommission.getCandidates();
            int voteIndex = new Random().nextInt(candidates.size());
            electoralCommission.acceptVote(voteIndex);
            try {
                cyclicBarrier.await(); //wait while all voters vote
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Main {
    public static final int VOTE_COUNT = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
        candidates.add("candidate_1");
        candidates.add("candidate_2");
        candidates.add("candidate_3");
        candidates.add("candidate_4");
        candidates.add("candidate_5");
        candidates.add("candidate_6");
        candidates.add("candidate_7");
        candidates.add("candidate_8");
        candidates.add("candidate_9");
        candidates.add("candidate_10");
        ElectoralCommission electoralCommission = new ElectoralCommission(candidates);
        CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(VOTE_COUNT, new Summarizer(electoralCommission));
        for (int i = 0; i < VOTE_COUNT; i++) {
            new Thread(new Voter(cyclicBarrier, electoralCommission)).start();
        }

    }
}

class Summarizer implements Runnable {
    static int roundNumber = 1;
    ElectoralCommission electoralCommission;

    Summarizer(ElectoralCommission electoralCommission) {
        this.electoralCommission = electoralCommission;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Round " + roundNumber++ );
        electoralCommission.printResults();
        electoralCommission.removeWeakCandidates();
        if (electoralCommission.hasWinner) {
            String winnerName = electoralCommission.getWinner();
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            System.out.println("candidate " + winnerName + " won!");
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your `acceptVote` method efficiency might be enhanced. Here, you instanciate an `AtomicInteger` per call to `acceptVote`, wether it is needed or not (and most of the times, it is not). Maybe you should, as discussed in other comments, pre-initialize you `Map` to 0 for each candidate, at the start of the election round.

Comment: @GPI agreed with your opinion